# SVG use tag outputting SVG differently

Tags: html, svg

If I copy the svg code directly into my code, the SVG appears differently than if I reference the SVG using the "use" tag.

Why do they appear differently?

(I would prefer to use the  reference method, but don't know why the background colour is added).

```html
<div>
<p>Using the entire SVG code within the HTML</p>
  <svg width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M5 9.00146L11.4697 15.4711C11.7626 15.764 12.2374 15.764 12.5303 15.4711L19 9.00146" stroke="#1E0564" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>

<!-- SVG code -->
<svg style="display:none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="chevron" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <title>Chevron</title>
    <desc>Chevron icon</desc>
    <path d="M5 9.00146L11.4697 15.4711C11.7626 15.764 12.2374 15.764 12.5303 15.4711L19 9.00146" stroke="#1E0564" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<!-- end SVG code -->

<p>Referencing SVG using &lt;use href=""&gt; tag</p>
<svg class="useSvg">
  <use href="#chevron" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first one is affected by the "fill" property of the svg, the last one is not. Also, note the viewBox is missing in the last svg#useSvg

Comment: The default fill of a shape is black. The first one is affected by fill="none" of the svg around it. For the useSvg, try this: `<use href="#chevron" fill="none"/>`

Comment: @qrsngky Adding a `viewBox` to the svg#useSvg will change nothing, the display size has to be set with `width` and `height` attributes (or CSS properties).

Comment: Thanks @qrsngky, the fill="none" on the "use" is what I needed.

Comment: @BradleyDong or you may add it on the path, depending on your use case

Comment: To make it pixel perfect; Minify the path with: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ With ``9.00146`` (N.nnnnn precision) you are now making the GPU work on stuffing 100_000 'pixels' into 1

Answer (score 0):

Like you commented yourself, you need to remove the fill by adding `fill="none"` to the path. In addition I cleaned up the path a bit.

```html
<div>
<p>Using the entire SVG code within the HTML</p>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 72 40" fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 8 8 L 34 34 C 35 35 37 35 38 34 L 64 8"
    stroke="#1E0564" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>

<!-- SVG code -->
<svg style="display:none" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="chevron" viewBox="0 0 72 40">
    <title>Chevron</title>
    <desc>Chevron icon</desc>
      <path d="M 8 8 L 34 34 C 35 35 37 35 38 34 L 64 8" fill="none"
      stroke="#1E0564" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<!-- end SVG code -->

<p>Referencing SVG using &lt;use href=""&gt; tag</p>
<svg class="useSvg" width="24" height="24">
  <use href="#chevron" />
</svg>
</div>
```